# "cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead" Help is appreciated

Tags: c#

*FIXED*

It was failing in 6 different spots in "form1.designer.cs". It said I needed to used it statically, so I changed all the errors from "this.xxxx" to "form1.xxxx" and it worked. Not sure I completely understand what I did though...

*FIXED*

Fairly new to programming here and just working on some basic OOP in C#. I am trying to call a method from another class in my Button Click event. The method passes one parameter which is user inputted text. I think the problem has something to do with the Method being static, but the parameter is dynamic, because it is user inputted. Please help me out!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string _yourName = textBox1.Text;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DogCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            AnimalNoise.Bark(_yourName);
        }

        if (CatCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            AnimalNoise.Meow(_yourName);
        }

        if (FishCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            AnimalNoise.Girgle(_yourName);
        }
    }
}




public class AnimalNoise 
{
    public static void Bark(String name) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(name + " Bark");
    }

    public static void Meow(String name)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(name + " Meow");
    }

    public static void Girgle(String name)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(name + " Girgle");
    }
}
```

Comment: initialize  _yourName = textBox1.Text; in constructor.

Comment: It was failing in 6 different spots in "form1.designer.cs". It said I needed to used it statically, so I changed all the errors from "this.xxxx" to "form1.xxxx" and it worked. Not sure I completely understand what I did though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can't access `textBox1` before it's actually created. You should capture the name inside the click callback. I think the error you're seeing might be because somewhere in your code you have something else called `AnimalNoise` you'll have to make sure there is nothing else called AnimalNoise and put AnimalNoise in it's own file.

Comment: There was nothing else called "AnimalNoise", just the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your exact problem isn't clearly stated but I believe you are not ever setting textBox1.Text.  Set it during your ButtonClick event.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _yourName = textBox1.Text;

        if (DogCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            AnimalNoise.Bark(_yourName);
        }

        if (CatCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            AnimalNoise.Meow(_yourName);
        }

        if (FishCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            AnimalNoise.Girgle(_yourName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Menefee. I was calling it is a class level variable, instead of inside the Button1Click. I think it will work either way.